# 8 bit barrel shifter using 2 x 1 MUX in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, multiplexer

Is it possible to write a VHDL code to exactly follow this diagram?[image]
I have written some codes before using subcircuits to form a larger circuit (for example 8 bit comparator using 1 bit comparators) and I'm wondering if I can do something similar here. Maybe use 2x1 MUX as a subcircuit or a component and go from there on?

Comment: Aha "exactly" like this"? Make 24 instances of 2x1 mux and just connect the signals.

Comment: Yes it is. You can use "for ... generate" to make it quite compact.

Comment: @MituRaj thanks, I managed to do it

Comment: @BrianDrummond thanks, I'll be looking into that. I defined 24 instances of port map and it's fine I guess, but could be shorter.